# want access resultset of first query for second query

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

This is java program for SQL statement. I have two queries. Result of the first query is required for second query.

How do I call it in second query?
These results are values for xml tags.

I need to get first query result for this tag

```
child1.setAttributeNS(xlink,"xlink:type","");
```

but this is located in 2nd query and if i try to merge those 2 query I get eror resultset closed.

```
         while(rs1.next()){
        int i=0,j=0 ,locid,supid;
        int lc[]=new int[100];
        int sp[]=new int[100];
      lc[i] =   rs1.getInt(2);
        sp[j] =   rs1.getInt(1);
        lcid=lc[i++];*/
         for(i=0;i<loc[i];i++){
        for(j=0;j<sup[j];j++){
          lcid=lc[i];  spid=sp[j];
      System.out.print(spid +" ");
       System.out.println(lcid);
  String     s = (lc[i]==1 ? "simple" : (lc[i]>1 ? "extended" : null));

         System.out.println(s);            }}}

      String querystring=
          " ";


        rs = stmt.executeQuery(querystring );
   while(rs.next()){
        Element child1 = doc.createElement("slink");

                          /
        Element element = doc.createElement("loc");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a brand new and separate `Statement` for the second `ResultSet`. Everytime you get a new `ResultSet` out of a single `Statement`, every previously opened one will namely be closed.

Replace

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery(querystring );
```

by

```
Statement stmt2 = connection.createStatement();
rs = stmt2.executeQuery(querystring);
```

Don't forget to add `stmt2.close()` to the `finally` block.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, have you considered just `JOIN`ing the both queries and using Javabeans to represent the model? This way you end up with a single query and more self-documenting code.

Comment: how do i create separate Statement?

Comment: The same way as you created the first statement. Only give it a different variable name :) `stmt2` or something.

Comment: I do not understand what you're not understanding. You need to get the second result set from a second statement. That's all.

Comment: Sorry, it's bed time for me now, I will put it in tomorrow if you still can't figure it out. See ya!